# Typescript: Getting undefined back from HttpClient.Post<T>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to type script and i am not sure what i am doing wrong here:

```
  async login(credentials: Credentials): Promise<boolean> {
    let res: AuthToken = await this.httpClient.post<AuthToken>(this.endpoint + '/session/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: this.headers }).toPromise();
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.auth_token);
    return true;
  }
```

If i call this method with await from my login component I see in the console output that *res* variable is a valid *AuthToken* response:

```
{
  "id": "73113e63-df5e-4e4e-bde4-29108ddaaafe",
  "auth_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.7cN74Adh5d2gAu4-R2fffvEhrLWuAKc6QxKEZZfi09E",
  "expires_in": 43200
}
```

But if I then try to access *res.auth_token* I get *undefined*

What am I doing wrong here?

```
authtoken.interface.ts
export interface AuthToken {
    id: string;
    auth_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
}
```

Comment: If I *await* the promise res.then is no accessible. Isn't that whole point of the async await?

Comment: may be it is not abe to parse in JSON, have you tried this res.json().auth_token

Comment: res.json() is a function of Http and not HttpClientModule if I am not mistaken. Hmm

Comment: but since the *post<AuthToken>* return a typed response the res is already a AuthToken. That's why I don't understand why that if I console.log(res) I get the full json string back but if I access the auth_token property it is undefined :-/

Comment: that is kind of strange to understand, I now dont see any apparent reason for it, try different way of calling the response may be like res["auth_token"]

Comment: hmm same result: undefined. I have some get methods implemented the same way. They work. Just the post does not.

Comment: see if typeof res is an "object"

Comment: I feel stupid now...the problem was not the typescript. The backend returned an indented json. For some reason it can not handle that. Thanks for your help :-)